# What does the "against" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He also poured fuel on a long-running debate over how government intelligence services should balance their desire to keep software flaws secret - in order to conduct espionage and cyber warfare - against sharing those flaws with technology companies to better secure the internet.

Source: http://in.reuters.com/article/us-britain-security-hospitals/more-disruptions-feared-from-cyber-attack-microsoft-slams-government-secrecy-idINKBN18820S

What does the "against" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the injected section indicated by the em dashes (`-`), the sentence reads:

> balance their desire to keep software flaws secret against sharing those flaws with technology companies

So the author is indicating the government services in question want to keep software flaws secret. But they do recognise that sharing them would mean the flaws get fixed and doing so would make the internet safer.

Obviously if they shared the flaws, then the flaws would no longer be secret. The debate is in which is more advantageous, having a secure internet or having known flaws that the services can exploit.

Thus this sentence uses "against" in relation to distinguishing the two sides of the mentioned "debate". You could even think of it in terms of an old style weighing scales, you may balance some amount of something, say flour, *against* a known weight, like a 500 gram weight. The word "against" indicates the action of comparison between the two.

Comment: So the author do not want to share these flaws with technology companies, am i right?

Comment: People *in general* (not necessarily the author) know that the intelligence services gain advantage by keeping the flaws secret, they *also* know that there are also advantages to making them public. This is where the "debate" part comes in, some people  believe the former advantage should be retained, but some believe the latter advantage outweighs it.

Comment: So the "against" means that the government wants to keep secret, and in other hand they have to inform companies of that secret to secure internet. Right?

Comment: The quote in question is not specific to a particular government or agency, nor that they *have* to inform companies, Just that there advantages to both options. Example: I like both apples and chocolate, for lunch I will only eat only one, therefore I need to *balance* my desire for the chocolate against an the advantage of being healthy with the apple.

Comment: Oh. So it means the intelligence services have two options, and they either keep secret or open to public.

Comment: @Xie Yun. In such a context as this the phrase '*as against*' is often used instead of the bare '*against*'. '*As against*' means  '*contrasted with*'. So the debate is about the value of keeping software flaws secret *as against / contrasted with* sharing those flaws with technology companies. The debate is still ongoing.

Comment: Somewhat simplified, the idiomatic usage is "to balance A against B", e.g. "For my trip next year, I need to balance [spending money on a good hotel] against [saving money so I can buy lots of souvenirs]". Doing A negatively impacts B (and vice versa), but you want to do both; therefore a balance must be struck.